# Populating list view using adapter with given one or two ArrayLists

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I have a list view in an Activity which I am populating with adapter with given ArrayList. In this class Elements the variables are kept.
So in this ListView I am having Categories, sub-categories and elements. In some cases there are only elements, in others only categories, in others categories and elements at the same time. The categories must be an element, which when clicked to go to another activitiy, and the element to be simple element displaying info.

In the case of having sub-categories and elements, I am creating a whole new ArrayList putting in it ArrayList and ArrayList, which then has 2 sub-arrays. Curently my adapter's constructor looks like this

```
public class AchivsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Elements> {

ArrayList<Elements> eItems;
ArrayList<Categories> cItems;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public AchivsListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Elements> ee) {
    super(context, resource, ee);
    this.eItems = ee;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

How can I make the adapter work with all given cases?

Comment: Is there any way you can abstract something common out of the Elements and Categories classes?  For sake of simplicity, we could call this new base class Thing.  Then you could have make your ArchivsListAdapter extend ArrayAdapter<Thing>.  Create a new instance variable called adapterArray of type ArrayList<Thing>.  This will be the array you bind the adapter to.  Then, in the constructor, perform the logic needed to figure out which set to use and put it in the adapterArray.  If you need both sets, iterate through and make adapterArray the way you want before setting it as the source.

Answer (score 0):

If categoryes and elements are similar objects I would edit the Element class and give to it a boolean attribute isCategory, so that you can have a single ArrayList of elements and in the adapter check if the current position contains a Category or an Element and set the onClickListener for the second.